# as adjective as to infinitive or as adjective to infinitive as

Tags: adverbial-phrases

> Older workers can be as adaptable and quick to learn as anyone else.

This sentence is from Oxford Advance Learner Dictionary. I wanted to know whether I can change this sentence as follow.

> Older workers can be as adaptable and quick as anyone else to learn.

Can I use "to infinitive" after "as adjective as"?

Comment: Almost. You'd really want "… as quick as anyone else to learn".

Answer (score 2):

There is no connection whatever between the *as adjective as* and the *to*. The only relevant relationship is that *quick* can take a *to* clause. The structure is

> as [[adaptable] and [quick to learn]] as anybody else.

Your amendment is effectively equivalent to

> as [[adaptable to learn] and [quick to learn]] as anybody else,

which is not idiomatic (some would say "not grammatical") because *adaptable* can't take a *to* clause. But if you substituted an adjective that can take a *to* clause, eg *eager*, then your recasting would be possible.

Comment: I think you mean "there's no connection **whatsoever**".

Comment: I wouldn't object to _whatsoever_. But in my variety of English, _whatever_ is more natural.

Answer (score 0):

Generally no. You need to keep "quick to learn" together because "to learn" modifies "quick". In terms of sentence structure, they act like a single adjective. Also, in the " is as  as " construction,  needs to come at the end of the clause; your re-ordering violates this rule.